# Django many-to many filter field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views, many-to-many

I want to add into the list if the region, contains that country, its a relation of M2M between the Region and Country models. i cant get to the attribute of the country code it says that "colon expected".
what is missed in the if condition?

views.py

```
notification = Notification.objects.filter(**condition). \
    exclude(notification_user__in=users). \
    order_by('notificationType__priority', '-start_date')
notifications = []

for n in notification:
    print len(n.region.all())
    if len(n.region.all())==0:
        notifications.append(n)
    else:
        if (region.countries__in=country):
            notifications.append(n)
```

Notififcation models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  description = models.TextField()
  start_date = models.DateTimeField()
  end_date = models.DateTimeField()
  application = models.ManyToManyField('Products.Application')
  notificationType = models.ForeignKey(NotificationType)
  url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
  region = models.ManyToManyField('Geolocations.Region', null=True, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
  user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Notification_User')
```

Geolocations models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
  code=models.CharField(max_length=2)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=36)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s - %s' % (self.code, self.name)
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural="Countries"

class Region(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
  countries=models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: that was a problem of the post, the identation is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

region.countries__in=country is an assignment, and because it is being performed in an if statement's condition, you are getting "colon expected".

If you want to check for a country being related to a region you can do this:

```
# country is the country's code
n.region.filter(countries_code=country).exists()
```

Comment: now it generates an error of "'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'country_set' "

Comment: what is region in this context, isn't it a region instance? Try directly: region.filter(id=country.id).exists()

Comment: if you check the models, region is an attribute of the table "notification" that is connected to the table "region" via M2M and the "country" is connected to the table "region" also via a M2M. And country is a variable that contains the country code, i cant compare and id vs country code and i want to compare the country codes

Comment: So not region, but n.region? Then I it should be n.region.filter(countries__code=country).exists()

Comment: Yap, i got there alone, if u could update your answer to close the topic.
Thanks for the "lights"